# Could I create multi dynamic_reconfigure in one package in one CMakeList？

Tags: ros, c++, cmake, rqt-reconfigure

I have two `*.cfg` files, each one working with its executable process.

The CMakeLists:

```
# dynamic reconfigure
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(config/ManualCalib_.cfg)
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(config/ManualCalibMainLidar_.cfg)

add_executable(manual_calib_node
    src/manual_calib_node.cpp
    src/manual_calib.cpp    
)

add_executable(manual_calib_main_lidar_node
    src/manual_calib_main_lidar_node.cpp
    src/manual_calib_main_lidar.cpp
    
)

# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")
set_target_properties(manual_calib_node PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "RECONFIGURE_FILE=\"ManualCalib_.cfg\"")
add_dependencies(manual_calib_node ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
target_link_libraries(manual_calib_node 
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${GLOG_LIBRARIES}
    yaml-cpp
    )
add_definitions("-DNODE_VERSION=\"${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}-${GIT_BRANCH}.${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}\"")

set_target_properties(manual_calib_main_lidar_node PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "RECONFIGURE_FILE=\"ManualCalibMainLidar_.cfg\"")
add_dependencies(manual_calib_main_lidar_node ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
target_link_libraries(manual_calib_main_lidar_node 
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${GLOG_LIBRARIES}
    yaml-cpp
    )
add_definitions("-DNODE_VERSION=\"${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}-${GIT_BRANCH}.${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}\"")
```

After `catkin` this error shows:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/dynamic_reconfigure-macros.cmake:84 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "lidar_manual_calib_gencfg" because
  another target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a
  custom target created in source directory
  "/home/peng/WorkSpace/lidar_manual_suit_function/src".  See documentation
  for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:60 (generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options)
```

The line 60 is:
`generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(config/ManualCalibMainLidar_.cfg)`

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Provide all the cfg files in a list instead of separate `generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options()` lines.  Change

```
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(config/ManualCalib_.cfg)
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(config/ManualCalibMainLidar_.cfg)
```

to

```
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
  config/ManualCalib_.cfg
  config/ManualCalibMainLidar_.cfg
)
```

I have an example of many dynamic reconfigure cfg in one cmakelists: https://github.com/lucasw/image_manip/blob/master/image_manip/CMakeLists.txt#L24